# How to manipulate HTML table once it's returned from backend like Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the situation: I use Node.js as my backend, and use markdown to edit and post my blog article. And when a client requests the specific URL, such as `http://www.example.com/blog/article_1`, I returned the blog contents from Node.js with some template like ejs, which would be something like the follows:

```
app.get("/blog/article1", function(req, res) {
    var article = something // this is a valid HTML converted from a markdown file
    res.render("article1", {
        title: "my blog article 1",
        article: article
    });
});
```

In the above code, I render `article.ejs` with `title` and `article` variable. The `article` variable is a valid HTML to be injected to the ejs template. So far, it' fine.

However, if I want to display a HTML table which is written in the original markdown file, with Bootstrap 3's responsive table functionality, (i.e. `<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">...actual table...</table></div>`), how can I do it? Right now the table in my markdown file is just a markdown file, and I don't think that it's the best idea to just modify all of my markdown files on which I insert or wrap with the `<div class="table-responsive">...</div>` line; the files might also be used in a situation other than Bootstrap.

In other words, is it feasible to dynamically or programmatically inject the responsive functionality to the table once the template is returned by Node.js?  And is it also feasible to inject the responsive table functionality selectively? (in other words choose arbitrarily some tables that I want to add the responsive function?)

Comment: What are you using to convert the markdown to html? There should be a point during that conversion where you can inject classes for standard elements like tables.

Comment: Timothy, I use [poet](https://github.com/jsantell/poet).

Comment: Poet uses Marked for Markdown parsing and compilation. Marked supports customizing the renderers to modify the html output. Unfortunately it doesn't look like Poet exposes any way for you to customize the Marked options. It hides all of the details behind the  createTemplates function in templates.js. You would likely have to modify Poet in order to expose the Marked object which you could then customize.

All of that would probably still be better than just modifying the HTML on the client side to add bootstrap classes.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm sure I'm not versed enough to be able to fork the module and modify the internals - after all, this is my first attempt to build on a web app. Right now it's probably the best to write some sort of command-line tools to parse and convert, and then deploy the converted files to the app, and later learn about the details of the Poet (including Marked) to customize it for my own use. Thank you a lot for the insightful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on from the comments: It's actually not that difficult to fork and modify a project. The faster you can get used to working with open source libraries the better your experience will be with Node. Things move pretty quickly in the Node world, and sometimes things won't work like they are expected to. You can either wait around for a fix, or roll up your sleeves and pitch in.

I found a way to update the markdown templates using their addTemplate method. However the version of Marked the project is using (2.8) doesn't support custom templates. I've [forked the repository](https://github.com/tstrimple/poet) and updated the version of marked as well as fixed the issues this caused with the tests. I also added a restriction to prevent it from using Express 4 which breaks all the tests. I submitted these as a [pull request](https://github.com/jsantell/poet/pull/86) to the original repo, but in the mean time you could use my version to write something like the following.

*untested*

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  Poet = require('poet'),
  marked = require('marked'),
  renderer = new marked.Renderer();

renderer.table = function(header, body) {
  return '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">' + header + body + '</table></div>';
}

var poet = Poet(app, {
  posts: './_posts/',
  postsPerPage: 5,
  metaFormat: 'json'
});

poet.addTemplate({ ext: 'markdown', fn: function(s) {
  return marked(s);
}});
```

Alternatively, if all you're using poet for is the markdown conversion, you might as well use marked directly and cut out the dependency on poet.

Comment: Awesome! What an aspiring work! One more question: why do you use `+ header + body + ` within `render.table = function(header, body)`? Looks like [Marked wraps them with thead and tbody within it](https://github.com/chjj/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js). Or maybe it's not necessarily the requirement in Bootstrap to use `thead` and `tbody` within tables?

Comment: thead and tbody are optional. You can include them if you are going to adjust style based on them. I'm not sure if twitter bootstrap uses them or not.

Comment: I just tried it and found that `marked(s)` should be `marked(s, {renderer: renderer})`, right? And I also found that this works well if I write the tables with markdown-syntax in my markdown file, but when I write those tables with HTML syntax (i.e. `<table><tr>..<th>..`) to the markdown file, then the rendering and parsing don't work... Is it still feasible to convert HTML tables as well as markdown tables? What's the best direction that I should take from here?

Comment: Maybe parse and convert the argument `s` in the Object assigned to `poet.AddTemplate()` using regex before passing it over to the `return (marked(s, {renderer: renderer}));`? I haven't tried it and have to first learn about JavaScript regex, so wouldn't be able to report the result soon, though...

Comment: Why are you using html tables inside markdown? If you're using html tables, then why not just include the css classes yourself?

Comment: Oops. I should have came up with it. That's so simple... As to the HTML tables, it's just that some of my old blog posts (around 15 ~ 20%) used HTML tables in markdown files.